# RFE from scikit-learn feature_selection with NegativeBinomial from statsmodels as estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I'm trying to use [RFE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) from scikit-learn with an estimator from statsmodels [NegativeBinomial](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.families.family.NegativeBinomial.html).

So I [created my own class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51686174):

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
import statsmodels.api as sm

class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, formula_, data_, family_):
        self.model = sm.formula.glm(formula, data=data_, family=family_)

    def fit(self, **kwargs):
        self.model.fit()
        self.coef_ = self.model.params.values

    def predict(self, X):
        result = self.model.predict(X)    
        return np.array(result)

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)


dataset = pd.DataFrame({'X1':X[:,0], 'X2':X[:,1], 'X3':X[:,2], 'y':y})

estimator = MyEstimator("y ~ X1 + X2 + X3", dataset, sm.families.NegativeBinomial())

selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=5, step=1)
selector = selector.fit()
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: fit() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'y'
```

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to require `endog` and `exog` variables, instead of using the `formula` API:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
import statsmodels.api as sm

class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, family_):
        self.family_ = family_

    def fit(self, exog, endog):
        self.model = sm.GLM(endog, exog, family=self.family_)
        fit_results = self.model.fit()
        self.coef_ = fit_results.params

    def predict(self, X):
        result = self.model.predict(X)    
        return np.array(result)

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)

estimator = MyEstimator(sm.families.NegativeBinomial())

selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=5, step=1)
selector = selector.fit(X, y.reshape(-1,1))
print(selector.ranking_)
# [1 1 3 1 1 5 1 6 4 2]
```